# Initialise size of std::array in a constructor of the class that uses it

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, std

Is it possible to use the `std::array<class T, std::size_t N>` as a private attribute of a class but **initialize its size in the constructor** of the class?

```
class Router{
    std::array<Port,???> ports; //I dont know how much ports do will this have
public:
    Switch(int numberOfPortsOnRouter){
        ports=std::array<Port,numberOfPortsOnRouter> ports; //now I know it has "numberOfPortsOnRouter" ports, but howto tell the "ports" variable?
    }
}
```

I might use a pointer, but could this be done without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the size must be known at compile time. Use `std::vector` instead.

```
class Router{
    std::vector<Port> ports;
public:
    Switch(int numberOfPortsOnRouter) : ports(numberOfPortsOnRouter) {
    }
};
```

Comment: But vector is for data types with "changing" lengths. The size of "ports" on the other hand is constant and can never change. I wonder if I will not loose some performance by using vector.

Comment: @user: How can you "lose performance" when one way works, and the other does not? Also, you can just choose not to resize the `std::vector`, giving you no "overhead" except the allocation when a `Router` object is created.

Comment: @user1459339: No, `vector` is for arrays of dynamic size == not known at compile time.

Comment: There is no performance loss, and secondly, you're comparing it to a method that *doesn't even work*.

Comment: So the theoretical magic array implementation could be more efficient. Vectors require a pointer indirection.  In theory the array could be stored in a larger instanceof the class, appended on the end or something.  Doing this in C is pretty standard.  Not sure of an easy way to do it in C++.

Comment: @Yakk: since C11 VLAs are optional and implementations are not required to support them.

Comment: In C you might stick a one sized array at the end of your struct then malloc memory that provides for as many entries as you would like in it.  In comparison to a C++ class with a vector this has one less pointer dereference to get at array elements.  There is no equivalent C++ technique that I know of, other than doing the C technique in C++...

Comment: @Yakk: Nothing stops you using the C technique. I thought at first that you were talking about C specific (VLAs).

Answer (score 8):

You have to make your class `Router` a template class

```
template<std::size_t N> 
class Router{
    std::array<Port,N> ports; 

...
}
```

in case you want to be able to specify the size of `ports` at `Router` *level*. By the way, `N` must be a constant known from compile time.

Otherwise you need `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes but then I would have to know the number N when passing Router into a function. For example "void foo(Router<???> r);" Anyway, I will use the vector.

Comment: It is convenient to `typedef` the `Router<>` class you will use, i.e. `typedef Router<20> MyRouter;`

Answer (score 3):

The size of an `std::array<T, N>` is a compile-time constant which can't be changed at run-time. If you want an array with flexible bounds you can use a `std::vector<T>`. If the size of your array doesn't change and you somehow know the size from its context, you might consider using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. It is a bit more light-weight but also doesn't help with copying or resizing.

Comment: "a bit more light-weight" == saves one word :) EDIT: actually saves nothing if you must store the size separately.

Comment: @ybungalobill: You don't have to store the capacity, so it does save one word.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: yep, but you are likely to end storing the size twice. Once for your own and once from inside the `operator new[]` implementation.

Comment: @ybungalobill: That additional overhead would apply to vector too, so unique_ptr is still 1 less.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Often you can infer the size from the context, e.g., when you have another array around. It also saves the capacity. `std::vector<T>` stores three word s which has a fair chance to be padded to four words. That is you save between 66% and 75% of the size of the control record. Also, when moving the object you need to touch only one word instead of three.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: NO! vector allocates with `allocator<>` which ends up calling `operator new(size_t)`, which does not track the 'number of elements' because it does not perform initialization/destruction.

Comment: @ybungalobill: `std::vector<T, A>` needs to store three or four pieces of information: the base address of the array, the number of current elements, its capacity, and potentially an allocator. The latter one can be avoided for stateless allocators using the empty base optimization. I don't think any of the others can be avoided although they don't need to be all stored in the actual `std::vector<T, A>` object (they can be partially prepended to the allocated object).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: does it somehow contradict what I said? The default allocator is stateless thus we can assume that `vector<T>` stores exactly three words, somewhere. Padding is usually performed to word boundary, so no padding here. vector's footprint: 3 words + allocated memory. `unique_ptr<T>` (also has to store a deleter, which is by default stateless so lets ignore it) stores a pointer + allocated memory + size of the array for delete[] + size of the array for you. As I said the last holds only "if you must store the size separately", i.e. cannot infer it.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Unless there is a stateful deleter, `std::unique_ptr<T>` itself store just one word: a pointer to the start of the memory. `std::vector<T>` itself normally stores three words, i.e., `sizeof(std::vector<T>) == 3 * sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T>)` (there are implementation techniques for `std::vector<T>` to also just store one word in the object itself but I'm not aware of any implementation using it). When allocating an array, the allocated memory for an array carries the size which `std::vector<T>` can safe. In return it normally overallocates.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is an array of **fixed** length. Therefore the length must be known at compile time. If you need an array with dynamic length, you want to use `std::vector` instead:

```
class Router{
    std::vector<Port> ports;
public:
    Switch(int numberOfPortsOnRouter):ports(numberOfPortsOnRouter){}
};
```